# Tox Not Respecting Defined envlist in Custom Environments

Tags: python, continuous-integration, tox

Given the following *tox.ini* file:

```
[tox]
envlist = py39
isolated_build = True
requires =
    tox-poetry-dev-dependencies

[testenv]
description = Default environment
commands =
    python --version

[testenv:mytestenvironment]
commands =
    python --version
```

I'm expecting `$ tox -r` and `$ tox -r -e mytestenvironment` to both yield `Python 3.9.7`, however, the later statement yields `Python 3.10.0`. My local environment, via `$ python3 --version` confirms that the default environment is `3.9.7`; I believe that `3.10.0` was introduced from a `brew upgrade` (apparently the latest *tox*, `3.24.4` requires Python `>=3.10.0`

The question is: how do I modify *tox.ini* to force usage of *Python 3.9*?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use the basepython in testenv for that  envlist is just default target environments, not configuration for environments.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, the following solved the problem (c/o [@Yeti](https://stackoverflow.com/users/296075/yeti))

```
[tox]
envlist = py39
isolated_build = True
requires =
    tox-poetry-dev-dependencies

[testenv]
description = Default environment
basepython = python3.9
commands =
    python --version

[testenv:mytestenvironment]
commands =
    python --version
```

The documentation: [Tox Configuration Specification::Tox Environment Settings::basepython](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html?highlight=basepython#conf-basepython)

> Complete list of settings that you can put into `testenv*` sections:
>
> ...
>
> `basepython(NAME-OR-PATH)`
>
> Name or path to a Python interpreter which will be used for creating the virtual environment, this determines in practice the python for what we’ll create a virtual isolated environment. Use this to specify the python version for a tox environment. If not specified, the virtual environments factors (e.g. name part) will be used to automatically set one. For example, `py37` means `python3.7`, `py3` means `python3` and `py` means python. `provision_tox_env` environment does not inherit this setting from the `toxenv` section.
>
> ...

Also, the `[testenv]` section is the "parent" for anyone else who didn't pick that up readily from the documentation.